# Connect Four Console App Lagging at move check

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Working on a C# connect four console app. I have the following code which is supposed to prompt a user to enter a row to drop a token into, display where it dropped, check if there's 4 in a row horizontally, vertically, and diagonally.

```
using System;

namespace connectfour
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[][] board = new int[6][];

        public struct playerInfo
        {
            public string playerName;
            public char playerID;
        }

        //Player 1 by default
        static int playerTurn = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            playerInfo playerOne = new playerInfo();
            playerInfo playerTwo = new playerInfo();

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Connect Four!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Player One, please enter your name: ");
            playerOne.playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            playerOne.playerID = 'X';
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Player Two, please enter your name: ");
            playerTwo.playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            playerTwo.playerID = 'O';

            int win = 0;

            CreateBoard();

            while (win == 0)
            {
                if (playerTurn == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(playerOne.playerName + " please select a row: ");
                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var userInput))
                    {
                        if (PlayerChoice(userInput, playerOne.playerID))
                        {
                            WinCondition(userInput, playerOne.playerID);
                            ChangeTurn();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (playerTurn == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(playerTwo.playerName + " please select a row: ");
                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var userInput))
                    {
                        if (PlayerChoice(userInput, playerTwo.playerID))
                        {
                            WinCondition(userInput, playerTwo.playerID);
                            ChangeTurn();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(win == 1)
            {
                EndGame(playerOne, playerTwo);
            }
        }

        static void CreateBoard()
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < board.Length; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column <= board.Length; column++)
                {
                    board[row] = new int[7];
                    Console.Write(((char)board[row][column]) + " . ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static bool PlayerChoice(int userInput, char playerID)
        {
            var isValidMove = false;

            if (userInput <= board[0].Length)
            {
                var row = GetRowForMove(--userInput);

                if (row != -1)
                {
                    board[row][userInput] = playerID;
                    DisplayBoard();
                    isValidMove = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't go there!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid row.");
            }
            return isValidMove;
        }

        static int GetRowForMove(int colChoice)
        {
            for (int i = board.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (board[i][colChoice] == 0)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        static void DisplayBoard()
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < board.Length; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < board[row].Length; column++)
                {
                    Console.Write(((char)board[row][column]) + " . ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        static void ChangeTurn()
        {
            if (playerTurn == 1)
            {
                playerTurn = 2;
            }
            else if (playerTurn == 2)
            {
                playerTurn = 1;
            }
        }

        static void WinCondition(int userInput, char playerID)
        {
            int win;

            win = 0;

            while (win == 0)
            {
                CheckHorizontal(userInput);
                CheckVertical(userInput);
                CheckDiagonalLeft(userInput);
                CheckDiagonalRight(userInput);
            }
        }

        //If player has 4 in a row horizontally
        static int CheckHorizontal(int userInput)
        {
            int XO = userInput;
            int win = 0;

            for (int row = board.Length - 1; row <= 5; row--)
            {
                for(int col = board[0].Length - 1; col <= 3; col--)
                {
                    if (XO != 0 &&
                        XO == board[XO][col - 1] &&
                        XO == board[XO][col - 2] &&
                        XO == board[XO][col - 3])
                    {
                        win = 1;
                    }
                }
             }
             return win;
            }

        //If player has 4 in a row vertically
        static int CheckVertical(int userInput)
        {
            int XO = userInput;
            int win = 0;

            for (int row = board.Length - 1; row <= 2; row--)
            {
                for (int col = board[0].Length - 1; col <= 3; col--)
                {
                    if (XO != 0 &&
                        XO == board[row - 1][XO] &&
                        XO == board[row - 2][XO] &&
                        XO == board[row - 3][XO])
                    {
                        win = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return win;
        }

        //If player has 4 in a row top-right to bottom-left
        static int CheckDiagonalRight(int userInput)
        {
            int XO = userInput;
            int win = 0;

            for (int row = board.Length - 1; row <= 2; row--)
            {
                for (int col = board[0].Length - 1; col <= 3; col--)
                {
                    if (XO != 0 &&
                        XO == board[XO + 1][XO + 1] &&
                        XO == board[XO + 2][XO + 2] &&
                        XO == board[XO + 3][XO + 3])
                    {
                        win = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return win;
        }

        //If player has 4 in a row top-right to bottom-left
        static int CheckDiagonalLeft(int userInput)
        {
            int XO = userInput;
            int win = 0;

            for (int row = board.Length - 1; row <= 5; row--)
            {
                for (int col = board[0].Length - 1; col <= 3; col--)
                {
                    if (XO != 0 &&
                        XO == board[XO - 1][XO + 1] &&
                        XO == board[XO - 2][XO + 2] &&
                        XO == board[XO - 3][XO + 3])
                    {
                        win = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return win;
        }

        static void EndGame(playerInfo playerOne, playerInfo playerTwo)
        {
            if(playerTurn == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connect Four, " + playerOne + " you win!");
            }
            else if(playerTurn == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connect Four, " + playerTwo + " you win!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that the console lags at the CheckHorizontal() and CheckDiagonalLeft() methods when stepping through them during debug...to the point that it doesn't even swap to the next player to prompt for a move.

Additionally, I'm trying to make the checks do so from the current token dropped, as opposed to checking the entire board each time...I'm not sure if my if statements express this correctly or not.

Can someone please lend some insight as to what's causing the console to lag and how I can accurately write these if statements?

Thank you!

Comment: In CheckHorizontal the for loop continues if row <= 5, and it's decrementing row.  So looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: @DaveG so the way I tried to set it up was to not count below the first row (0) as I was getting out of range exceptions thrown on those checks. What would be the best way to fix that, not decrement and set the row <= 6 as it's a 6x7 board?

Answer (score 1):

There might be more issue, but one below causes infinite loop:

```
while (win == 0)
{
    CheckHorizontal(userInput);
    CheckVertical(userInput);
    CheckDiagonalLeft(userInput);
    CheckDiagonalRight(userInput);
}
```

your "win" is always 0 and loop never ends.

Your WinCondition method should return boolean value and look rather like:

```
    static bool WinCondition(int userInput)
    {
        return CheckHorizontal(userInput) == 1 ||
            CheckVertical(userInput) == 1 ||
            CheckDiagonalLeft(userInput) == 1 ||
            CheckDiagonalRight(userInput) == 1 ||;
//you can modify Check... methods to return bool as well, it would be more readable
        }
    }
```

And in main method there should be something like:

```
if(WinCondition(userInput))
{
    win = 1;
}
else
{
    ChangeTurn();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the details on that. However, when using the WinCondition as you have it it's giving me errors stating that the operator "==" cannot be applied to type int or bool.

Additionally, If I add the if condition to main it tells me that WinCondition doesn't apply in the current context. I'm not quite sure why that is...

I initially thought the if statements in the checks could also return true, but the return bool type has to be outside the if (and for) statements. Therefore I'm not sure what the if statements should actually result to?

Comment: Did you modify WinCondition method the way I showed above? Also, where exactly did you put this if(WinCondition…) part? It was supposed to replace  WinCondition(userInput, playerOne.playerID);
                            ChangeTurn();

Comment: ah my mistake. I replaced the if as you stated. But still modifying the WinCondition method as you stated still gives me errors that the Check methods do not exist in the current context...additionally a namespace cannot directly contain fields or methods and every mention of "board" inside the check methods no longer exist in the current context

Comment: My mistake now - one } too many in WinCondition(). remove it and it'll be fine